# Retrieve Listview items and display a column data as combo box display member and other value as value member

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, combobox

I have a list view with two columns- name and number. I want to read all these items and assign name to a combo box display member and number to value member. I have tried thinking the approach to follow but couldn't help myself. This is what I have tried. How should I proceed?

```
    public class numbers
    {
        public string name;
        public string number;
    }
    public class names : List<numbers>
    { 

    }
    names cname = new names();

    public void addcontacts()
    {
        foreach(ListView lv in bufferedListView1)
        {
         //No idea how to proceed
```

Comment: What do you want to do in `addcontact()`? If i understand you right, you just want to display all the items in your `ListView` in your `ComboBox`?

Comment: Yes. When I call `addcontact()` all the name column's data of the listview should be added to combo box. And all the number column data should be added to corresponding name values in combobox (I mean to **value member** property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you set your own type:

```
public class myContact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public myContact(string name, string number)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Number = number;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Then you transfer all items from the listview to the combobox like this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new myContact(item.Text, item.SubItems[0].Text));
}
```

This example assumes, that each listviewitem holds the name and that its first child holds the number.

When you add objects to the combobox, C# will use the objects' ToString() method to create something that you can actually see when the program is running. You override the default ToString() method with your own and only return the name. If you want to use the selection from the combobox you just cast the selectedItem back to myContact and can access the number there. Welcome to OOP :)

Comment: An `foreach` on `Items`? What if there are millions of items?

Comment: First, its a very cheap operation. Second, you wouldn't display millions of items in a listview and especially not copy them to a combobox.

Comment: @Jan Thanks. Could you also tell me how to retrieve the value of the selected item. I want to display the combo box selected item's value in a textbox. I tried but couldnot get how to do it

Comment: try this: `myContact contact = (myContact)comboBox1.SelectedItem` With that you retrieve the object from the combobox and cast it back to an object of type `myContact`. You can then retrieve the number with `string number = contact.Number`